# How to debug native memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I was told that Android has some mechanism to debug "memory leak" issue. And one of them is based on `libc_malloc_debug_leak.so`.

So, I did following steps to enable this feature:

**1**. Make sure `libc_malloc_debug_leak.so` and `libc_malloc_debug_qemu.so` exist in `system/lib`.

**2**. Input these commands in an `adb` shell:

```
adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc 1   /* then use getprop to check its value */
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

I expect to get memory info by catching log.

However, the actual result is that my device cannot startup and a native crash occurs (seems crash at `malloc` or `free`).

My device is an Android phone.

Did I use correct approach? If no, what would it be?